# count grade while looping by using answer in streamwriter?

Tags: c#, loops, streamwriter

Can someone look at my code? How do I count the grade while looping, or can I take the line from StreamWriter and put substring? 
I keep making it more and more messy... and I need to display it like

Student that score A got how many?
Student that got B got how many?>
student that got C how many>
student that got d ... f...

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Student.txt"))
{
    StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("Result.txt");
    String line;
    line = reader.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {

        String name = line.Substring(0, 9);
        String Asg1 = line.Substring(10, 3);
        String Asg2 = line.Substring(16, 3);
        String Test = line.Substring(22, 3);
        String Quiz = line.Substring(28, 3);
        String Exam = line.Substring(34, 3);

        int intAsg1 = int.Parse(Asg1);
        int intAsg2 = int.Parse(Asg2);
        int intTest = int.Parse(Test);
        int intQuiz = int.Parse(Quiz);
        int intExam = int.Parse(Exam);

        int percentAsg1 = (intAsg1 * 25) / 100;
        int percentAsg2 = (intAsg2 * 25) / 100;
        int percentTest = (intTest * 10) / 100;
        int percentQuiz = (intQuiz * 10) / 100;
        int percentExam = (intExam * 30) / 100;


        // this part i dont get it~ 
        **String Grade;
        if (overallScore >= 70)
        {
            Grade = "A";
        }
        else if (overallScore >= 60)
        {
            Grade = "B";
        }
        else if (overallScore >= 50)
        {
            Grade = "C";
        }
        else if (overallScore >= 40)
        {
            Grade = "D";
        }
        else
        {
            Grade = "F";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To get the best answer can you post a sample line from the file

Comment: Can you try and make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: after i got the grade i want to put it in array or what, so that i can count the "Grade" how many student get

Answer (score 1):

It's not looping.

```
while !reader.EndOfStream
{
  /*now check each Readline.
    parse each line and create a new grade object for 
    each iteration and add to collection*/
}
```

A custom class to store the data for each student:

```
public class grade
{
 public int asg1{ get; set; }
 public int asg2{ get; set; }
 public int test{ get; set; }
 public int quiz{ get; set; }
 public int exam{ get; set; }
 //whatever else you need
}
```

A collection of Grades:

```
var grades = New List<grade>
```

Comment: then how do i count the overall score? in there

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a class to hold the results in addition to correcting the readline loop.

```
public class Student
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a list before you start the loop

```
var students = new  List<Student>();
```

Then add to the list in each iteration